# Applying noise with constraints

Tags: normal-distribution, noise

I need to add noise distribution. Noise from a normal distribution would be best.

- An input vector ${x} \in [0,1]$ is given which the vector sums to one.
- A noise is generated and `applied` to $x$
- The resulting **noised** $x$ should still sum to 1 and in range $x\in[0,1]$. And the weights of the elements are not too far off from the original input.

How can I achieve this?

I tried generating noise from noise and normalizing it with dividing with the sum. But some noise is negative, so summation could end up with 0 denominator.

Comment: I gave up and sampled from uniform $[0, n]$ and normalized with the sum

Comment: I would ask what you're trying to achieve by adding the noise, and why you think normal noise would be "best".

Comment: @ConvMan I'm working on resource allocation problem. The elements of the input vector are the fraction of let's say workers allocated to $task_i$. I wanted to do some exploration of the weights but not too far from the weights I initially set. By using normal noise, I am able to sample more weights closer to the initial weights. and less weights far from initial weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to tackle the problem, but adding normal noise with no restrictions is going to make things a bit harder for you given your constraints.

Perhaps a more stable option, which avoids the issues of negative values entirely, is to consider multiplicative rather than additive noise. If we draw $\delta_i$ from some distribution of strictly positive values, then we can take $y_i = x_i \delta_i$, and then setting $x_i' = \frac{y_i}{\sum y_j}$ gives us:

1. $x_i' \geq 0$
2. $\sum x_i' = 1$

Which are two of the desired properties. The third property, wanting $x_i'$ to be somehow "close" to $x_i$, will come by choosing a distribution for $\delta_i$ that is centred around 1 and isn't too variable. One option is to make $\delta_i \sim U(1-d,1+d)$ with $d \in (0, 1)$.